# Jigsaw puzzle game - Puzzle pieces put into carousel slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am making a jigsaw puzzle game.

I have done:

- make image into puzzle pieces.
- puzzle pieces interlocking working fine.
- puzzle pieces rotate on mouse wheel.
- on click to move puzzle piece working fine.

What I have to do:

- when puzzle created then make one carousel slider like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wvdd7b31/) but it's not exactly what want just for hint.
- I made a JS fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hgkubavat08/0L8o1oLr/), but I got an error of `self.gadgets is undefined` in console, this is just for your demonstration you see my above working project.

I have to do like below images

[image: Screen shot Image]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error "self.gadgets is undefined" because you are never defining self.gadgets. You do have a gadgets variable though. To fix your error try adding self.gadgets = gadgets; after you are done defining the gadgets object.

Comment: can u update my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgkubavat08/0L8o1oLr/) i tried your answer but don't get result.

Comment: I edited it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jross53/zjrgp269/1/. The error is gone now. It does look like there are some messages about requesting insecure images that may be causing problems (requesting images from url starting with http when your current url starts with https). The browser will not allow you request those images like that. You may need to open the html file in a browser on your local machine so the images are not being requested from a secure site (over https).

Comment: i update the whole image (over https) url, but dont' create any puzzle pieces for that image, like [this](http://104.128.228.134/puzzle/), & this fiddle example just only create for my question need for more explanation. so if you have any idea for my question than let me know. and by d way thank you for your time. but i didn't get any solution ; ( .

Comment: I saved the html to my computer as well as the javascript and css all in separate files and referenced the javascript and css files from the html file and I'm able to get the puzzle to display. There is something going on with jsfiddle. Can you try doing as I did and saving the code on your computer? Does it work if you do that?